# Почему так происходит? C++, инициализация данных

Tags: c++, указатели, инициализация

Имеется вот такой код

```
class Test {
    double* data;
public:
    Test();
    Test(int a);
};
Test::Test() {
    Test(5);
}
Test::Test(int a) {
    data = new double [a];
}
```

однако если в программе вызвать

```
Test* test = new Test();
```

data будет 0x0000000000000000 почему так происходит? если инициализировать при помощи второго конструктора( с параметром который) тогда всё нормально сразу, но только стоит вложенный использовать все данные куда то пропадают, при отладке их тоже видно, до момента выхода из второго конструктора

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вызов конструктора, как и другие действия инициализации, должен находится в списке инициализации, а не в теле функции:

```
Test::Test(): Test{5} {
}
Test::Test(int a): data{new double [a]} {
    
}
```

`Test(5);` в теле функции создает безымянный временный объект, а не вызывает конструктор для этого объекта.

`data = new double [5];` присваивает новое значение указателю, а не инициализирует его (хотя тут это ни на что не влияет).

Comment: `: Test(5)` тоже будет работать.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю такой вариант:

```
...

Test::Test() {
    data = new double [5];
}

...
```

Comment: Используйте инициализацию, а не присваивание.